# Does GitHub support VFS for Git?

Tags: git, github

**NOTES:**

1. I really hope that this question hasn't been asked before and as far as I know, only Azure DevOps Service (Azure DevOps on cloud) and Azure DevOps Server 2019 (Azure DevOps on-premise) fully supports VFS for Git.
2. VFS in this context is Virtualized File System for Git. It is not VFS in Linux. The same virtualized, but this VFS is specific to ease managing large Git repository.

---

For those who don't know VFS for Git, VFS for Git is helpful to ease managing Git because it has virtualized file system that help managing large size repo, especially for those repo that has size > 2GB.

For more information, please visit the official landing page of VFS for Git: https://vfsforgit.org/

My question is, when will GitHub support VFS for Git? As far as I know, in early 2018, it says it will support but still no further update until now.

Comment: For those who downvotes my question, please elaborate. I'm new here, and if it's OOT please tell me.

Comment: Mostly this kind of question should probably be directed towards GitHub / Microsoft, someone might have specific experience so you may get an answer, but you will probably get a better answer directly from Microsoft or GitHub.

Comment: @RichardSlater I have tried that asking MS and GitHub. They just keep giving me vague answer. As far as I know my, I have tried to have VFS to any GitHub repo, and GitHub still doesn't have it.

Comment: We're all in the same boat there I'm afraid, quick google about turns out lots of vague responses.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono Did you try it?

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono Did you check the maximum repository size at GitHub? E.g. bitbucket repository are allowed to be 2GB max.

Comment: @030 I have tried it. I mean, last time I tried was last week. It still doesn't support VFS for Git.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono Could you create a ticket at https://support.github.com/ as suggested by @RichardSlater? Please post it as an answer once you have created it so more people could track the progress.

Comment: @030 ok, I'll try to create a support ticket on GitHub tomorrow. I'll also post an update on this VFS matter if there's any reply. I hope this question will not be closed, because it is relevant for Git, GitHub, and still within the scope of the overall DevOps.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono I will not close it.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono Did you create an issue?

Comment: I have created an issue, but latest response from them is quite vague :(
They say that it supports VFS, but there's no scheduled roadmap for actual implementation support. I am currently escalating this further.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub doesn't support VFS. There are news articles in 2017 saying GVFS and later VFS would be supported by GitHub. As of today, there is no support and no planned support for it.

My sources:

- https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit/issues/1640
- https://github.community/t/vfsforgit-setup/128184
- https://github.community/t/microsofts-virtual-filesystem-for-git/2092
- The Github public roadmap says nothing related to VFS or anything similar. https://github.com/github/roadmap